# Migrating from WPF in MVC4 - with WCF

Tags: jquery, wpf, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been mostly working WPF for the last few years, and need to implement a web MVC4 interface with similar behavior.  I previously used Asynchronous WCF methods and Observable collections to track state changes in rendered data.

For example, I build a WPF Observable Collection of square objects that are initially rendered black, based on the first WCF call from the ViewModel.  I would iterate through the collection and make multiple WCF async calls.  When the results are asynchronously returned to the ViewModel, it would determine if the object state has changed, then render the changes via the Observable collection bindings to change the relevant square from black to red.

How would i go about this type of Observable collection behavior in MVC4?

1. Reuse the Async WCF services directly from an Async Controllers and update the View changes.
2. JQUERY AJAX calls + MVC Web API that in turn call the Async WCF services.
3. Mixture of 1 & 2

Comment: Web applications are very different in nature from Desktop applications. For one, the Web is **Stateless** and there's no such thing as "update the View from the Controller". The Controller (Server Side) simply returns a result (usually HTML [+ CSS + JavaScript]) to a request (HTTP) from the Client (Web Browser), which then renders the HTML-based UI. This UI is completely on the Client side and there's no way for Server side code to reach that. You need think everything in terms of requests and responses.

Comment: I do need to rethink the current web, as i am stuck in the old ASP.NET web forms habits.  I am trying to wrap my head around refreshing the View when the model changes, as i would normal do everything from server-side code behind.